# Detecting invalid grammar with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a simple grammar for evaluating logical expressions.

The "single" conditions are of the type

```
keyword = value
keyword != value
```

Then, I want to allow logical combinations grouped with parentheses, 
e.g.

```
cond1 & cond2 & cond3
cond1 & ( cond2 | cond3 )
(cond1 & cond2) | cond3
cond1 | cond2 | cond3
```

but not logical combinations where left/right associativity would matter
and confuse the users. So the following would be disallowed:

```
cond1 & cond2 | cond3
```

If I understand it right, this latter requirement stops me from using `operatorPrecedence()`,
and I would anyway like to understand it on a lower level.

The following grammar takes me almost where I want:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, nums, oneOf, Literal, Group, Suppress, \
                        Forward, ZeroOrMore, ParseException, StringEnd
comparison_op_list = ['=', '!=']
logical_op_list = ['&', '|']
# Pyparsing expression for single conditions
keyword = Word(alphas + nums + '_.:-')
comparison_op = oneOf(comparison_op_list)
value = Word(alphas + nums + '_.:-;')
single_condition = keyword + comparison_op + value
# Pyparsing expression for combined condition
lpar = Literal( '(' )
rpar = Literal( ')' )
logical_op = oneOf(logical_op_list)
combined_expr = Forward()
atom = single_condition | ( Suppress(lpar) + combined_expr + Suppress(rpar) )
combined_expr << Group(atom) + ZeroOrMore( logical_op + combined_expr )

# Examples
test_strings = [
    'keyword = value',
    'keyword1 = value1 & keyword2 = value2',
    'a=a & (b=b|c=c) & (d=d & (e=e|f=f))',
    'a=a & ((b=b|(c=c))) & (((d=d) & (e=e|f=f)))',
    'test1=A & test2=B | test3 = C'  # Parses fine, but later rejected in python code
]
for s in test_strings:
    print
    print s
    print combined_expr.parseString(s)
```

Output:

```
keyword = value
[['keyword', '=', 'value']]

keyword1 = value1 & keyword2 = value2
[['keyword1', '=', 'value1'], '&', ['keyword2', '=', 'value2']]

a=a & (b=b|c=c) & (d=d & (e=e|f=f))
[['a', '=', 'a'], '&', [['b', '=', 'b'], '|', ['c', '=', 'c']], '&', [['d', '=', 'd'], '&', [['e', '=', 'e'], '|', ['f', '=', 'f']]]]

a=a & ((b=b|(c=c))) & (((d=d) & (e=e|f=f)))
[['a', '=', 'a'], '&', [[['b', '=', 'b'], '|', [['c', '=', 'c']]]], '&', [[[['d', '=', 'd']], '&', [['e', '=', 'e'], '|', ['f', '=', 'f']]]]]

test1=A & test2=B | test3 = C
[['test1', '=', 'A'], '&', ['test2', '=', 'B'], '|', ['test3', '=', 'C']]
```

From this I can handle valid input in regular python.
The problem is that some invalid grammar is also read without error:

```
invalid_strings = [
    'a b = c',  # Rightfully rejected 
    'word1 = word2 != word3', # Read as 'word1 = word2'
    'keyword = value_with_*illegal*_characters' # Read as 'keyword = value_with_'
]
for s in invalid_strings:
    try:
        result = combined_expr.parseString(s)
    except ParseException:
        result = None
    print
    print s
    print result
```

Output:

```
a b = c
None

word1 = word2 != word3
[['word1', '=', 'word2']]

keyword = value_with_*illegal*_characters
[['keyword', '=', 'value_with_']]
```

For the above examples without logical combinations, I could probably
use StringEnd to require that the string ends immediately after the expression. 
But that would not work when conditions are combined with logical operators(?)
Is there a way to require that all parts of an input expression be recognized as
part of the grammar, or would this be out of pyparsing's scope and the task of
e.g. PLY?

Comment: You can force parseString to fail on extra characters after a successful parse if you include the `parseAll=True` arg. Also, you should be able to just call `combined_expr.runTests(test_strings)` to test your examples.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcGuire, this solved my problem. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.